# How can I run multiple instances of a Docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want to to multiple instances/replicas of the same image.

Consider an image `workerA` which has been build.

```
docker build --tag=workerA .
```

I usually run it with

```
docker run --net=host -p 18080:8080 -t -i workerA
```

Now I want to run it several replicas of this docker container.I looked into the [swarm documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/) and create a compose file as

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: workerA:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 4G 
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "18080:8080"
    network_mode: "host"
```

Usually the worker would connect to host server, grab data and perform a task but the server never receives any request. How can I check what my `workerA` terminal outputs? I seems I am able to create the replicas

```
$ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE               PORTS
y0sf30vqaoj1        warokerASwarm_web        replicated          2/2                 workerA:latest    *:18080->8080/tcp
```

but they seem not to be in the same network or preform the way I was used to when a single instances of docker is running.

Comment: I am no docker expert, but I think you have to create a network for all container via `macvlan` with your `docker network create ...` command. To get the output of a running docker container have a look at `docker attach` command. Example `docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=... --ip-range=... --gateway=... -o parent=... yourNetworkName`. To run your container within the same network as the hosts and other containers use: `docker run -d --network=yourNetworkName containerName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode)

> The option **network_mode** is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a (version 3) Compose file.

If you're expecting it to behave the same way, as when running a single container, it won't happen.

If there's no specific reason for using `version: '3'` you may use `version:'2'` instead.

Or you can let it create its own network, which it does with your current docker-compose file.

If you want to use host network instead, please take note of these limitations ([from docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)):

> In Docker 17.06 and higher, you can also use a host network for a swarm service, by passing --network host to the docker container create command. In this case, control traffic (traffic related to managing the swarm and the service) is still sent across an overlay network, but the individual swarm service containers send data using the Docker daemon’s host network and ports. This creates some extra limitations. For instance, if a service container binds to port 80, only one service container can run on a given swarm node.

Comment: So how can I let the swarm behave similar to running a single container.

Comment: If I get you correct, that's some sort of default behavior. You use the published port to call the service, and it internally chooses one of the running containers (called tasks) to handle your request. There's no extra work to be done. 

In the getting started [example](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/) you choose as a starting point, you can see that on every refresh, the host name changes. You still use one port (like you did when there was just one container), the magic happens behind the scenes

Comment: Ok. But can the docker container inside the swarm make calls to the other services from the outside. Since it looks like the docker container inside the swarm is not making any calls